# How to resolve "Failed to lookup view "list" in views directory".?

Tags: javascript, express, ejs

Here is my code,

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");

const app = express();
app.set("view engine", "ejs");

app.get("/", function(req, res){
    var today = new Date();
    var currDay =  today.getDay();
    var day = "";

    if(currDay == 0){
       day = "Sunday";
    }
    else if(currDay == 1){
        day = "Monday";
    }
    else if(currDay == 2){
        day = "Tuesday";
    }
    else if(currDay == 3){
        day = "Wednesday";
    }
    else if(currDay == 4){
        day = "Thrusday";
    }
    res.render('list', {todayDay : day});
});
 
app.listen(4000, function(){
    console.log("Hey, you are in port 4000");
});
```

I am watching angela yu's web dev course while I got stuck in the phase where the error is this.

Error: Failed to lookup view "list" in views directory "C:\Users\ASUS\Dropbox\PC\Desktop\To-do\views"
at Function.render (C:\Users\ASUS\Dropbox\PC\Desktop\To-do\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:597:17)
at ServerResponse.render (C:\Users\ASUS\Dropbox\PC\Desktop\To-do\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:1039:7)
at C:\Users\ASUS\Dropbox\PC\Desktop\To-do\app.js:33:9
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\ASUS\Dropbox\PC\Desktop\To-do\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
at next (C:\Users\ASUS\Dropbox\PC\Desktop\To-do\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:144:13)
at Route.dispatch (C:\Users\ASUS\Dropbox\PC\Desktop\To-do\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:114:3)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\ASUS\Dropbox\PC\Desktop\To-do\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
at C:\Users\ASUS\Dropbox\PC\Desktop\To-do\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:284:15
at Function.process_params (C:\Users\ASUS\Dropbox\PC\Desktop\To-do\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:346:12)
at next (C:\Users\ASUS\Dropbox\PC\Desktop\To-do\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:280:10)

Please if anybody can help me out.?

Answer (score 0):

the `list` file must be in a directory called `views`
and you need to add it to the app

```
const path = require('path')
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
```

this error is telling that it cannot find the filed called `list`